# can't make Genesis footer widgets stack when page resizing for responsive theme

Tags: html, css, wordpress, genesis

For days Ive been trying to correct an error in my CSS for this website. Everything is fine except for the footer area. It looks fine on desktop but as soon as its seen on small screen the footer area doesn't respond, the background colour disappears and and it gets very messy. If someone could help me id greatly appreciate it. Im no expert on CSS and am shooting in the dark.... the site is a test @ http://test.apinchofsalt.ie/wp/

All i need is the simplest solution to fix it. thanks very much. Below is the relevant CSS (it includes footer widgets, site footer and media queries)
/* Footer Widgets
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- */

```
    .footer-widgets {
    background-color: #222;
    color: #c8c8c8;
    clear: both;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-size: 1.4rem;
    }
   .footer-widgets .wrap {
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 60px 30px 30px;
    }
    .footer-widgets-1,
    .footer-widgets-2,
    .footer-widgets-3 {
    padding: 0 2.8%;
    width: 33.3333333333%;
   }
  .footer-widgets-1,
  .footer-widgets-2 {
   float: left;
   }
   .footer-widgets-3 {
   float: right;
   }
  .footer-widgets .widget {
   margin-bottom: 30px;
   word-wrap: break-word;
   }
   .footer-widgets a:focus {
   color: currentColor;
   }
  .footer-widgets li {
  background: url(images/icon-li-footer.png) no-repeat 0 7px;
  background-size: 8px 8px;
  }
   .footer-widgets .search-form {
   width: 100%;
    }
   /* Site Footer
```

---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- */

```
   .site-footer {
   color: #222;
   font-size: 12px;
   font-size: 1.2rem;
   padding: 40px 0;
   text-align: center;
   text-transform: uppercase;
   }
   .site-footer a {
   color: #222;
   }
   .site-footer p {
    margin: 0;
   }
  /* Media Queries
```

---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- */

```
    @media only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5),
    only screen and (-moz-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5),
    only screen and (-o-min-device-pixel-ratio: 3/2),
    only screen and (min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5) {
    .search-form input[type="search"] {
    background-image: url(images/icon-search@2x.png);
    }
    .sidebar li {
    background-image: url(images/icon-li@2x.png);
    }
    .footer-widgets li {
    background-image: url(images/icon-li-footer@2x.png);
    }
    .content #genesis-responsive-slider .flex-direction-nav li a {
    background-image: url(images/icon-direction-nav@2x.png);
    }
    .content #genesis-responsive-slider .flex-control-nav li a {
    background-image: url(images/icon-control-nav@2x.png);
    }
    .genesis-nav-menu > .rss > a {
    background-image: url(images/icon-rss@2x.png);
    }
    .genesis-nav-menu > .twitter > a {
    background-image: url(images/icon-twitter-nav@2x.png);
    }
    }
    @media only screen and (max-width: 1200px) {
    .site-container {
    max-width: 960px;
    }
    .site-header .widget-area {
    width: 700px;
    }
    .content {
    width: 660px;
    }
    .sidebar-primary {
    width: 300px;
    }
    .title-area {
    width: 260px;
    }
    .breadcrumb {
    margin: -30px -40px 30px;
    }
    .content {
    padding: 30px 40px 10px;
    }
    .site-header .genesis-nav-menu a {
    padding: 38px 14px 40px;
    }
    .content #genesis-responsive-slider .flex-control-nav,
   .content #genesis-responsive-slider .flex-direction-nav li a,
   .content #genesis-responsive-slider .flex-direction-nav li a.prev {
    display: none;
    }
    }
    @media only screen and (max-width: 1023px) {

    .site-container {
        max-width: 768px;
    }

    .content,
    .sidebar-primary,
    .sidebar-secondary,
    .site-header .widget-area,
    .title-area,
    .wrap {
        width: 100%;
    }

    .header-image .title-area,
    .header-image .site-title,
    .header-image .site-title a {
        background-position: center !important;
        float: none;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }

    .genesis-nav-menu li,
    .site-header ul.genesis-nav-menu,
    .site-header .search-form {
        float: none;
    }

    .genesis-nav-menu,
    .site-header .search-form,
    .site-header hgroup,
    .site-title {
        text-align: center;
    }

    .genesis-nav-menu a,
    .genesis-nav-menu > .first > a,
    .genesis-nav-menu > .last > a,
    .site-header .genesis-nav-menu a {
        padding: 16px;
    }

    .site-header .search-form {
        margin: 16px auto ;
    }

    .genesis-nav-menu li.right {
        display: none;
    }

    .content #genesis-responsive-slider .slide-excerpt {
        display: none;
    }

    .sidebar .widget {
        padding: 30px;
    }

    .comment-list li.depth-1,
    .ping-list li.depth-1 {
        margin: 30px 0;
    }

    .footer-widgets .widget-area {
        padding: 0;
    }

    .site-footer p {
        padding-left: 30px;
        padding-right: 30px;
    }

}

@media only screen and (max-width: 800px) {

    .site-container {
        max-width: 630px;
    }

    .five-sixths,
    .footer-widgets-1,
    .footer-widgets-2,
    .footer-widgets-3,
    .four-sixths,
    .home-middle .widget,
    .home-top .widget,
    .one-fourth,
    .one-half,
    .one-sixth,
    .one-third,
    .executive-pro-portfolio .portfolio,
    .three-fourths,
    .three-sixths,
    .two-fourths,
    .two-sixths,
    .two-thirds {
        margin: 0;
        width: 100%;
    }

    .site-title {
        margin-bottom: 20px;
    }

    /* Genesis Responsive Menus */
    .js .site-header nav .wrap {
        padding: 0;
    }

    nav.genesis-responsive-menu {
        background: #fff;
        display: none;
        position: relative;
    }

    .genesis-skip-link .skip-link-hidden {
        display: none;
        visibility: hidden;
    }

    .menu-toggle,
    .sub-menu-toggle {
        border-radius: 0;
        border-width: 0;
        color: #64c9ea;
        display: block;
        margin: 0 auto;
        overflow: hidden;
        text-align: center;
        visibility: visible;
    }

    .menu-toggle:focus,
    .menu-toggle:hover,
    .sub-menu-toggle:focus,
    .sub-menu-toggle:hover {
        background-color: #fff;
        color: #222;
        border-width: 0;
    }

    .menu-toggle:focus,
    .sub-menu-toggle:focus {
        outline: 1px solid #ccc;
        outline-offset: -1px;
    }

    .menu-toggle {
        background-color: #fff;
        line-height: 20px;
        margin-bottom: 1px;
        position: relative;
        z-index: 1000;
        width: 100%;
    }

    .menu-toggle::before {
        margin-right: 10px;
        text-rendering: auto;
    }

    .sub-menu-toggle {
        background-color: transparent;
        float: right;
        padding: 14px 10px 13px;
        position: absolute;
        right: 0;
        top: 0;
        z-index: 100;
    }

    .sub-menu .sub-menu-toggle {
        padding: 9px 10px;
    }

    .sub-menu-toggle::before {
        display: inline-block;
        margin-top: 5px;
        text-rendering: auto;
        -webkit-transform: rotate( 0 );
        -ms-transform:     rotate( 0 );
        transform:         rotate( 0 );
        -webkit-transition: transform .25s ease-in-out;
        -ms-transition:     transform .25s ease-in-out;
        transition:         transform .25s ease-in-out;
    }

    .sub-menu-toggle.activated::before {
        -webkit-transform: rotate( 180deg );
        -ms-transform:     rotate( 180deg );
        transform:         rotate( 180deg );
    }

    .genesis-responsive-menu ul {
        border-bottom: 2px solid #f2f2f2;
    }

    .genesis-responsive-menu .genesis-nav-menu .menu-item {
        display: block;
        float: none;
        position: relative;
        text-align: left;
    }

    .genesis-responsive-menu .genesis-nav-menu .menu-item:focus,
    .genesis-responsive-menu .genesis-nav-menu .menu-item:hover {
        background: transparent;
        position: relative;
    }

    .genesis-responsive-menu .genesis-nav-menu a:focus,
    .genesis-responsive-menu .genesis-nav-menu a:hover {
        color: #64c9ea;
    }

    .genesis-responsive-menu .genesis-nav-menu .menu-item a {
        background: transparent;
        border: none;
        color: #222;
        margin-bottom: 1px;
        padding: 15px 20px;
        width: 100%;
    }

    .genesis-responsive-menu .genesis-nav-menu .sub-menu {
        border: none;
    }

    .genesis-responsive-menu .genesis-nav-menu .menu-item > a:focus ul.sub-menu,
    .genesis-responsive-menu .genesis-nav-menu .menu-item > a:focus ul.sub-menu .sub-menu {
        left: 0;
        margin-left: 0;
    }

    .genesis-responsive-menu .genesis-nav-menu > .menu-item-has-children > a::after {
        content: none;
    }

    .genesis-responsive-menu .genesis-nav-menu .sub-menu {
        clear: both;
        display: none;
        margin: 0;
        opacity: 1;
        padding-left: 15px;
        position: static;
        width: 100%;
    }

    .genesis-responsive-menu .genesis-nav-menu .sub-menu .sub-menu {
        margin: 0;
    }

    .home-middle,
    .home-top,
    .genesis-pro-portfolio .pro-portfolio.entry .entry-header .entry-title {
        text-align: center;
    }

    .home-cta .button.alignright {
        float: none;
        margin: 16px 0 0;
    }

    .footer-widgets-1 {
        margin: 0;
    }

}

@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {

    .entry-title {
        font-size: 24px;
        font-size: 2.4rem;
    }

    .content .entry-header .entry-meta .entry-comments-link {
        display: none;
    }

}

@media only screen and (max-width: 270px) {

        .header-image .site-title a {
        background-size: contain !important;
    }
        .site-title {
        font-size: 26px;
        font-size: 2.6rem;
    }

}
```

Comment: just to say that the child theme comes with 3 footer widgets. I added an extra 2 through the functions.php. That may be where the problem lies.

Answer (score 0):

In your media queries pls include the following code. The footer widgets are floated and thus need clearing for the background to wrap around properly.

```
.footer-widgets .wrap:after {
content: "";
display: table;
clear: both;}
```

Comment: thats great Shivanand ill try it now

Comment: that doesnt seem to be working at all and the site footer hasnt changed - it seems to be in the way and doesnt drop beneath the footer widgets.

Comment: I tested your site in firefox and the footer widgets are responsive: they collapse below each other on smaller resolutions. Looks perfectly responsive. Is that not what you are expecting?

Comment: yep i changed a bit around...went into w3schools and looked up position values and thanks to you concentrated on the wrap - still dont understand what your code means though...but your help has been invaluable